# Numerical Linear response

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

I have two lists: 
the first is {t,f[t]} and the second {t,l[t]}.

What i need is the first order expansion of f[t] in l[t]:

$f(t)\sim f(t)\vert_{l(0)}+\int_{0}^{t}d\tau\; l(\tau)\;\frac{\partial f(t)}{\partial l(\tau)}\big\vert_{l(0)}+\dots$

There is a way to do it?

Comment: Have you considered replacing `f[t]` with `f[InverseFunction[l][s]]` and working from there?

Comment: Might get better responses if actual lists are posted.

Comment: Daniel the lists are very long, how can i post them?

Comment: Then try to find shorter lists, or come up with a representative subset of your actual lists.